# How to Remove Duplicates based on Timestamp?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyr

I am trying to remove duplicates based on the timestamp. So which every ID number came in first would stay, while the older one would be removed.

Having trouble figuring out how to approach this.

```
structure(list(sample = c(101496859, 101496859, 101496189, 101496189, 
101495613, 101495613, 101486260, 101486260, 101463063, 101463063, 
101461751, 101461751, 101458494, 101458494, 101450202, 101450202, 
101446157, 101446157, 101446089, 101446089), time = c("10/4/2019 6:05:28 PM", 
"10/4/2019 4:57:02 PM", "10/4/2019 7:51:52 PM", "10/4/2019 4:24:14 PM", 
"10/4/2019 7:01:44 PM", "10/4/2019 3:53:41 PM", "10/4/2019 1:24:32 PM", 
"10/4/2019 3:04:04 PM", "10/4/2019 11:07:29 AM", "10/4/2019 10:18:38 AM", 
"10/4/2019 2:05:08 PM", "10/4/2019 12:06:21 PM", "10/4/2019 12:50:33 PM", 
"10/4/2019 9:41:40 AM", "10/4/2019 10:29:09 AM", "10/4/2019 11:48:47 AM", 
"10/4/2019 7:55:10 AM", "10/4/2019 12:19:13 PM", "10/4/2019 11:30:35 AM", 
"10/4/2019 8:54:41 AM")), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried and the problems you've encountered. Also, `ID number` is not a column in your data, what is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `dplyr`

```r
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
  mutate(time = as.POSIXct(time, format="%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p", tz=Sys.timezone())) %>% 
  group_by(sample) %>% 
  arrange(time) %>% 
  filter(time == first(time)) %>%
  mutate(time = format(strptime(time, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p"))

#> # A tibble: 10 x 2
#>       sample time                  
#>        <dbl> <chr>                 
#>  1 101446089 10/04/2019 08:54:41 AM
#>  2 101446157 10/04/2019 07:55:10 AM
#>  3 101450202 10/04/2019 10:29:09 AM
#>  4 101458494 10/04/2019 09:41:40 AM
#>  5 101461751 10/04/2019 12:06:21 PM
#>  6 101463063 10/04/2019 10:18:38 AM
#>  7 101486260 10/04/2019 01:24:32 PM
#>  8 101495613 10/04/2019 03:53:41 PM
#>  9 101496189 10/04/2019 04:24:14 PM
#> 10 101496859 10/04/2019 04:57:02 PM
```

Comment: So when I use the full data sheet, i see that it drops all the other variables. How would i run this, while keeping all the other variables?

Comment: @DannyRamirez see my update. Instead of `summarise` I used `filter`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option after converting to `DateTime` class.  After grouping by 'sample', get the index of `min`imum 'Datetime' class converted 'time' column in `slice` to return that row

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df1 %>% 
    group_by(sample) %>% 
    slice(which.min(mdy_hms(time)))
# A tibble: 10 x 2
# Groups:   sample [10]
#      sample time                 
#       <dbl> <chr>                
# 1 101446089 10/4/2019 8:54:41 AM 
# 2 101446157 10/4/2019 7:55:10 AM 
# 3 101450202 10/4/2019 10:29:09 AM
# 4 101458494 10/4/2019 9:41:40 AM 
# 5 101461751 10/4/2019 12:06:21 PM
# 6 101463063 10/4/2019 10:18:38 AM
# 7 101486260 10/4/2019 1:24:32 PM 
# 8 101495613 10/4/2019 3:53:41 PM 
# 9 101496189 10/4/2019 4:24:14 PM 
#10 101496859 10/4/2019 4:57:02 PM
```

Answer (score 0):

In base R, we can `order` the data based on `time` and select the first row for each `sample`

```
aggregate(time~sample, df[do.call(order, transform(df, 
       time = as.POSIXct(time, format = "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p"))),], head, 1)

#      sample                  time
#1  101446089  10/4/2019 8:54:41 AM
#2  101446157  10/4/2019 7:55:10 AM
#3  101450202 10/4/2019 10:29:09 AM
#4  101458494  10/4/2019 9:41:40 AM
#5  101461751 10/4/2019 12:06:21 PM
#6  101463063 10/4/2019 10:18:38 AM
#7  101486260  10/4/2019 1:24:32 PM
#8  101495613  10/4/2019 3:53:41 PM
#9  101496189  10/4/2019 4:24:14 PM
#10 101496859  10/4/2019 4:57:02 PM
```

---

To keep all other columns, we can use `ave`

```
df[as.logical(with(df[do.call(order, transform(df, 
      time = as.POSIXct(time, format = "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p"))),][1:2], 
     ave(time, sample, FUN = function(x) seq_along(x) == 1))), ]
```